# xslt - combining subelements matching on their element text

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to come up with an XSLT transform template that can combine sub-elements matched by their element text (which can be anything)

Example input XML

```
<test>
    <name>Alpha</name>
    <value>11</value>
</test>
<test>
    <name>Beta</name>
    <value>14</value>
</test>
<test>
    <name>Alpha</name>
    <value>22</value>
</test>
```

I would like the transform to combine the subelements with matching  elements, so any subelements with name Alpha would be grouped in the output.

Example result XML

```
<test>
    <name>Alpha</name>
    <valuelist>11,22</valuelist>
</test>
<test>
    <name>Beta</name>
    <valuelist>14</valuelist>
<test>
```

The values of the text for name can be anything, so cannot be specifically noted in the template match.

Comment: It is a (typical) grouping problem. Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9?

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="test" group-by="name">
                <test>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                    <valuelist>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/value" separator=","/>
                    </valuelist>
                </test>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGbV.